# org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$MalformedStreamException: Stream ended unexpectedly

Tags: java, web-services

I have built the web service which uploads a file to a folder,and worked fine when tested with postman but when I call this web service from java application or android app it is throwing the exception "Stream ended unexpectedly".
Here is the stack trace of the exception thrown

> org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream$MalformedStreamException:
>   Stream ended unexpectedly     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.MultipartStream.readHeaders(MultipartStream.java:520)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.findNextItem(FileUploadBase.java:880)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileItemIteratorImpl.(FileUploadBase.java:845)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.getItemIterator(FileUploadBase.java:256)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:280)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2868)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParameters(Request.java:3216)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParameter(Request.java:1137)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParameter(RequestFacade.java:381)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:75)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.8.0_161]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   [na:1.8.0_161]

here is web service src code:
@RestController
public class FileUploadController 
{
    private static final String UPLOAD_FOLDER="C:\Users\Sagar\Uploads";

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload",headers ="content-type=multipart/form-data",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("file")MultipartFile multipartFile)
{
    if(multipartFile.isEmpty())
    {
        return "Please select a file to upload";
    }
    saveFile(multipartFile);
    return "Successfully uploaded "+multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
}

private void saveFile(MultipartFile multipartFile) 
{

    try 
    {
        byte[] bytes=multipartFile.getBytes();
        String data=new String(bytes);
        System.out.println(data);
        Path path=Paths.get(UPLOAD_FOLDER+File.separator+multipartFile.getOriginalFilename()+File.separator);
        Files.write(path, bytes);
    } catch (IOException e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

And this is the java code

public class Client 
{

```
private static final int B = 0;
private static Object uploaded_file;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String urlString="http://192.168.1.5:8888/upload";
    HttpURLConnection connection;
    String filePath="C:\\Users\\Sagar\\Uploads\\025_program.txt";
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
    String boundary="WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW";
     String linrEnd="\r\n" ;
     String twoHyphens = "--";
     int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

    try 
    {
        URL url=new URL(urlString);
        try 
        {
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            connection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+boundary);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/plain");
                ByteArrayOutputStream bs=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bs.write((twoHyphens+boundary+linrEnd).getBytes());
                bs.write(("Content-Disposition: form-data; file="+"Program.txt").getBytes());
                bs.write(linrEnd.getBytes());
                bs.write(("Content-Type:text/plain").getBytes());
                bs.write((linrEnd).getBytes());


            try
            {

                int bytesAvailable=fileInputStream.available();
                int bufferSize=Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
                byte[] buffer=new byte[bufferSize];
                int bytesRead=fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);
                while(bytesRead>0)
                {
                     bs.write(buffer,0,bufferSize);
                     bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                     bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                     bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }
                bs.write((twoHyphens+boundary+twoHyphens).getBytes());
                String dataOutput=new String(bs.toByteArray());
                System.out.println(dataOutput);

                OutputStream outputStream=new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                byte[] out=bs.toByteArray();
                outputStream.write(out);
                outputStream.close();

            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e2) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            int responseCode=connection.getResponseCode();
            String responseMessage=connection.getResponseMessage();
            if (responseCode==200) 
            {
                System.out.println("File Uploaded Successfully");

            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Response Code:- "+responseCode+"\n"+responseMessage);
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } 
    catch (MalformedURLException e1)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

}